# Showing status bar push down all views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, facebook-login, uistatusbar

I have this setup:
A view controller (**MAIN**) with a scroll view that goes to all edges, and 4 child view controllers (**A, B, C and D**) inside that scroll view. The first 3 controllers (**A, B and C**) are tutorials, and the fourth one (**D**) is a choose login controller.

In this 4th view controller (**D**) I have a login facebook functionality, that modally presents the facebook login dialog screen (**F**), but the facebook controller (F) has the status bar not hidden.

My problem is that when I tap the button, all the views in the 4th screen (**D**) get pushed down 20 pixels right before the Facebook dialog screen (**F**) appears, resulting in an ugly glitch.

**Note**: If I pin a view to the **MAIN** view controller, that view doesn't get pushed at all.

[image: Left is with status bar, right is without. red view is pinned to top of scroll view from **MAIN**, blue one is pinned to top of self.view of **D**. Both shift]

And a video as well:
[Video](http://makeagif.com/i/v9Vo6k)

And also a print of the screenshots. Nothing fancy. Plus the scroll view created with code.
**MAIN** controller on the right, **D** on the left

[image]

Comment: Please post image stating your issue . Your question is to broad

Comment: sure. I am adding a video as well and screenshots with the constraints as well